# cron job does not wait end of process

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I made a script which execute commands and others scripts. Some of these actions take time. When I execute my script manually from the cli, it work fine waiting the end of each instruction before go to the next one.

But when I put the script in a cronjob, even with "wait" command after each instruction, it does not wait the end of the instruction before starting the next one.

In result, I have empty mail send away.

Did anyone know what make this difference in behavior ?
Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT : cron job line

```
20 17 28 * * bash /home/rancid/running_script/for_crontab.sh
```

and script

```
# This scripts create an error file by reading the logs of rancid.
# Once the error file is created, It archives the logs in a tar archive
# and delete the logs files. It then send the error file as attachment
# by e-mail

REPO="/home/rancid/running_script"

# versionning and logs by rancid
echo "Versionning des confs par rancid en cours..."
rancid-run &
wait

# Create error file from what can be found in rancid log files
# (one per rancid group)
echo "Creation du fichier d'erreur en cours.."
bash $REPO/create_rancid_error_from_log.sh &
wait

# Create tar archive with the log files and then delete the logs
bash $REPO/tar_logs.sh &
wait

# Sending email with error file made earlier as attachment.
echo "Preparation du mail en cours..."
bash $REPO/mailmonitoring.sh &
wait

# Backup of rancid finished
echo "sauvegarde hebdomadaire terminee"
```

Comment: Add cronjob line and script to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should just get rid of `&` and the `wait` will become obsolete. You can replace it with `sleep 2` just to make sure everything is in place on time.

```
#!/bin/bash
REPO="/home/rancid/running_script"

# versionning by rancid
echo "Versionning des confs par rancid en cours..."
rancid-run &
sleep 10

# Creation du compte-rendu d'erreur
echo "Creation du fichier d'erreur en cours.."
bash $REPO/create_rancid_error_from_log.sh
sleep 2

# Archivage des logs suivi de leur supression
bash $REPO/tar_logs.sh
sleep 2

# Envoie du mail
echo "Preparation du mail en cours..."
bash $REPO/mailmonitoring.sh
sleep 2

echo "sauvegarde hebdomadaire terminee"
```

Comment: The original script did not have those. I've tried with those to see if the problem persist and it does ^^
If will try with sleep but i am not sure how it will improve since rancid-run time of execution can vary from 2 to 4 hours. I will keep you updated

Comment: notice that I did left the `&` after rancid run. it should go into background. I fear that the script does something else than it is intended by you. I do not speak french so maybe you could translate comments or write a description what this script should be doing?

Comment: If your intention is to process the logs after the rancid run process finishes, there should be no `&` after rancid run.

Comment: Just replaced the french comment by english comment. It is my intention to process the logs after the rancid run process finishes. I need it to be completed before doing anything

Comment: ok. the script is just wrong in my opinion. you should start a rancid run process, capture the pid number, enter while loop with a `sleep 1` command in it, in this loop you should check whether the pid is in use (process is still running)  and exit the loop when the pid is not found among the processes. Then you will perform the action on the logs and send email.

Comment: Here is how you get your pid: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30370/how-to-get-the-pid-of-the-last-executed-command-in-shell-script

Comment: Thank you for your observation and advices. I thought if something wrong with the beginning what is it and I finally found that the PATH is not the same on my differents users and crontab, so it does not have the path of rancid binaries. That's why it was working manually. I now capture the rancid-run process to have a proper implementation.